# Change name while application crashes and critical problems in my code

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

Anyone, please help me. 
 How to change the name of the Demo in message box.i need to change project name here.
 A problem caused the program to stop working correctly. Windows will close the 
 program and notify you if a solution is available.

[MESSAGE BOX IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMwAB.jpg)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you start your program with Visual Studio, what problem/exception is shown ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Some time shows "Demo has stopped working".i want to change "project name here has stopped working.Is it possible?

Comment: Are you the developer of the Demo ?

Comment: I don't know demo name where is coming from.My project name is different from the demo.I am a developer and not developer of the demo.